# Finding number of distinct pair in a string

Tags: java, distinct-values

Suppose there is a string s =abcaa and integer k=3.

I have to find the number of pairs (i,j)such that the number of distinct letter in sequence Si,Si+1,Si+2,...,Sj−1,Sj is exactly equal to K. same letters are considered equal and different letters are considered distinct.

S[i:j] denotes the sequence Si,Si+1,....,Sj−1,Sj

Since,K=3

Possible pairs (i,j) such that number of distinct letters in S[i:j] is exactly equal to K are:

(1,3) and S[1:3]=abc

(1,4) and S[1:4]=abca

(1,5) and S[1:5]=abcaa

(2,4) and S[2:4]=bca

(2,5) and S[2:5]=bcaa

So the answer is 5.

```
public class Coin {
public static void main(String[] args) {        
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    int k=in.nextInt();
    String str=in.next();
    solve(str,k);
}

private static void solve(String str,Integer k) {
    char[]ch=str.toCharArray();
    Map<Integer, Character> mapchar = new LinkedHashMap();
    for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++){
       mapchar.put(i,ch[i]);             //put the value of array index i and array value in mapchar i=keys ch[i]=values
    }
    int l=str.length(),count=1,i=0,store=0,j=1;
    while(i<l && j<=l ){
        if(mapchar.get(i)!=mapchar.get(j)){
            count++;
            if(count==k){
                store++;
               // count=0;
            }
        }
        else{
            if(count==k){
                store++;
            }
            else{
                count++;
            }
        }
        if(j==l){
            i++;
            j=i+1;
            count=0;
        }
        j++;
    }
    System.out.println(store);

     } 
  }
```

in the above code what will be the initial value of count(0 or 1)
{if value of count is 1 then a!=b then a!=c so count will be 3 then it will increment store...
but if the count is 0 then its value is 2 and store will not be incremented[having count=0 make sense but having count=1 doesnt make sense]}

second error is the commented count=0(i don't know where to put it)
because if it is commented then

```
 else{
        if(count==k){
            store++;
        }
```

will work and abca will be counted otherwise it will not be counted.(i dont know wheter to put it there or not).

Thirdly, which one is better LinkedHashMap,HashMap or TreeMap for the above question.

Comment: Are you trying to come up with a solution for classic [Coin-Change-Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem)

Comment: This is a que which i am trying to solve from hacker earth.https://www.hackerearth.com/july-circuits/algorithm/little-shino-and-coins-3/

Comment: That's a flavour of coin-change problem. I'll give you a hint and allow you to solve the rest. Iterate over each pair you mentioned and check how many of them has 'k' distinct characters. And this can be done using simple array.

Comment: @sbaitmangalkar  i did with array but iam getting 3.here is the code: 
[link](http://pastebin.com/gLdxqhD4)

Comment: I saw your code, the problem I guess is with the `count` and `store` values getting incrementing and decrementing. I will suggest a simpler solution. Create a array of `int` of size 26, representing the alphabets. Maintain 2 variables, difference and result. Loop through each `char`, again for each `char`, increment the position in the helper array. Check if helper array has that value as 1. if true, increment difference. If `diff == k` increment result. Finally return result. Bingo!!

Comment: Try it out first, I've given you the entire algorithm. If you still have doubts, I'll post the answer.